# Random max-width for each image on a page

Tags: jquery, image, grid, css

I have a grid of images, all set to have a max-width of 200px, but I'm wondering if there's any way to use jQuery or the like to set random max-widths for every image of the page so when masonry kicks in it works to an array of max-width images, probably with the maximum max-width being around 300px.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize jQuery's `$.each()` to iterate over a set of images and you can use `Math.random()` to create random `max-width` properties for those images:

```
$.each($('img'), function (index, obj) {
    $(this).css({
        'max-width' : (275 + (Math.random() * 50))
    });
});
```

This will set the `max-width` CSS property of all the images on the page to somewhere in-between `275` and `325`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wuY3H/1/ (Note that for the demo I changed the random threshold to allow small `max-width`s)

Some docs for ya:

- `$.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each
- `Math.random()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: @Richard A good going-though the docs would be in order I believe: http://api.jquery.com (so you know what in all you can do with jQuery)

Comment: Thanks, Jasper. I meant to ask, as I am using masonry, is there anyway to trigger masonry once all the max-widths have been set? It's throwing back some strange results due to it all loading at once.

Comment: @Richard I have not used Masonry however I assume you should run the above code before initializing Masonry (`$('#selection-id').masonry();`). Or refresh Masonry after the above code:  `$('#selection-id').masonry( 'reload' );`